# How to allow data:image attribute in src tag during post insert?

Tags: wp-insert-post, wp-kses, allowedtags

I'm inserting a post using `wp_post_insert()`. And my post's content looks like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAN4AAAB6CA { ... }
```

but on the insert process, Wordpress `removes` the data attribute. So above code becomes this:

```
 <img src="image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAN4AAAB6CA { ... }
```

I've tried something like this but no luck:

```
function my_filter_allowed_html($allowed, $context){
if (is_array($context)) {
    return $allowed;
}

if ($context === 'post') {
    $allowed['img']['data'] = true;
    $allowed['src']['data'] = true;

}

return $allowed;
}
add_filter('wp_kses_allowed_html', 'my_filter_allowed_html', 10, 2);
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [naththedeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/930917/naththedeveloper) from StackOverflow. His [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59092362/8486896) worked for me.

> Well, this was a nightmare to find, but I think I've resolved it after digging through the WordPress code which hooks in through `wp_insert_post`. Please add this to your `functions.php` file and check it works:

```
add_filter('kses_allowed_protocols', function ($protocols) {
    $protocols[] = 'data';

    return $protocols;
});
```

> Essentially internally in WordPress, there's a filter that checks the protocol of any URL's in the content and strips any which it doesn't like. By default, the supported list doesn't support the data protocol. The above function just adds it to the list of supported protocols.

> This filter does not run if you're an administrator, which is probably why you're seeing this issue only when logged out.

Thank you for your research.